# Fit in that role, fit for that role

Tags: word-choice

If someone thinks that a particular actor is suitable for a particular role, then what will be a natural way to say that:

> She's fit for that role.
>
> She'll fit in that role

Or should it be:

> She's suitable for that role.

Or

> She suits that role.

Comment: You may want to look over the help section on tagging - it has some advice for choosing tags: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these say approximately the same thing, with subtle differences. "She's fit for that role" and "she's suitable for that role" are equivalent; both imply that she has the necessary qualities to perform the role, irrespective of her actually performing it or not. The only tense information in the sentence is contained in "she is," which tells us she has those qualities currently.

"She'll fit in that role" suggests that she is being or has been cast for the role and will perform it in the future. "She suits that role" suggests that she is already performing the role.

The similar "she would fit in that role" or "she would suit that role" suggest, like the versatile case above, that she is inherently qualified for the role, but exclude the case where she is already performing it.

The differences all come down to verb tense. Sentence (3) is in the simple future tense, (4) is in the simple present tense, (5) and (6) use the subjunctive mood, and (1) and (2) use only an adjective phrase.

Comment: Sure, it works. There are lots of perfectly good ways to say the same thing: "She's a good fit for that role," "she's suited to that role," "she's/she would be a good [title of role]," just for a few examples.

Comment: The way you paraphrased kind of makes me think you don't understand the subjunctive, though. "She would" and "she will" are two different tenses, one hypothetical (not real) and one in the future (real).

Comment: And last question: what will sound more natural: "she fits that role" or "she fits in that role"?       (I mean what will be more likely to be used?)

Comment: And in this sentence,  "she fits this role" has "in" been dropped here?

Comment: It hasn't really been dropped, it's just that "fits" can function as either a transitive or an intransitive verb. To answer your first question, in general I'd say "she fits that role" sounds more natural.